# Return expired members using SQL - bigint date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to return a list of lapsed members using sql within phpMyAdmin. I can return a list using the below but don't think it's accurate being that there is no conversion happening on the date - which is stored as `bigint(11)`.

```
`SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `paypal_item` LIKE '%plus%' AND `valid_until` < '2017-11-29'`
```

I've also tried the below code running a conversion on the date but this is returning a zero result set.

```
`select from_unixtime(`valid_until`,'%Y-%m-%d') as 'due_date' from `users` where `paypal_item` like '%plus%' and 'due_date' < '2017-11-29' `
```

Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: can you show table data/ ddl

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL's `FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_timestamp, format)` as follows,

```
 SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(`valid_until`/1000000, "%Y-%m-%d") AS due_date 
    FROM `users` where `paypal_item` LIKE '%plus%' and due_date < '2017-11-29' ;
```

I am assuming here that your time contains microseconds.That is why `valid_until` get divided by 1000000(to convert to seconds) before conversion.

Ref:

- [MySQL FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)